# Why the fatal error: Array index out of range show when print array in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am new in Swift. I create a **node swift** file to store the node information. And the other **group swift** file is a group which store the all node.

The code of **`Node.swift`** is like the following:

```
class Node {

    var id:UInt8=0
    var type:Int=0
    var name:String=""
    var bdAddr:NSUUID!

    //The node private packet counter
    var nodePktNum:Int=0
}
```

The code of **`Group.swift`** is like the following:

```
class Group {

    var mLedDevice:[LedDevice]? = [LedDevice]()

    class LedDevice {
        var node            :Node?
        var rssi            :Int?
    }

    func allocateNode()
    {
        print("mLedDevice![0].node = \(mLedDevice![0].node))")
    }

}
```

When I try call function (`allocateNode`) and try to print `mLedDevice![0].node)` via `print("mLedDevice![0].node = \(mLedDevice![0].node))")`

It show the error `fatal error: Array index out of range`.

Did I missing something for initialize of `var mLedDevice:[LedDevice]? = [LedDevice]()` ?

Thanks in advance.

===================================EDIT=================================

I want to add the item into array , so I create a parameter like let `let leddevice : LedDevice` , and try to give it some value. And add the leddevice into `array mLedDevice`. But it show **`constant 'leddevice' used before being initialized`**.

How to give the init value for `let leddevice : LedDevice` ?

```
func allocateNode()
{
  let leddevice : LedDevice
  leddevice.node?.id = UInt8(0)
  leddevice.node!.bdAddr = NodeUUID
  mLedDevice?.append(leddevice)
}
```

Comment: Have you added any LedDevice object to the array. You created the array but it's empty one after then you are trying to access first element (mLedDevice![0]) which not exists and this produce the error

Comment: Your array is empty, `allocateNode()` should first add the node to the array, then print it

Comment: Please read the chapter about Initialization in the Swift Language Guide

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think about that can cause this is that the array is empty i.e. you are attempting to access index 0 of that array but that doesn't exist.

Try the following and it may give you an insight on how to solve it after seeing the content of the array:

```
print("mLedDevice = \(mLedDevice))")
```

In other words you are instantiating an array with no elements in it.

Comment: Thanks! But I meet the new question when I try to add the item into array. it show constant 'leddevice' used before being initialized...how to give it a init vale ?  There has many parameter in type `LedDevice`...

Comment: @Martin try using var instead of let. Does that help?

Comment: @Martin show us the code where you give it a value...it might help further

Answer (score 1):

In your line of code

```
var mLedDevice:[LedDevice]? = [LedDevice]()
```

You are only initializing an empty array. What you are trying afterwards is to access the first element, *of an empty array*, which is out of bounds.

Before your print statement, you will need to add an item to your array

```
var ledDevice = LedDevice()
mLedDevice.append(ledDevice)
```

And then your print statement would not give you any errors.

**UPDATED: Answer for the added question**

`let leddevice : LedDevice` is defining a constant of type `LedDevice` but is not yet initialized, and then it is being used in the next lines of code. You should replace it with

```
let leddevice = LedDevice()
```

Which will also initialize the variable.

*Note:* If you have any further questions, you should write a new question for that.
*Note2:* Have you read any [guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) about initialization?

Comment: Thanks! But I meet the new question when I try to add the item into array. it show constant 'leddevice' used before being initialized...how to give it a init vale ?  There has many parameter in type `LedDevice`...